# After 2 images slided in right side, next page is blank

Tags: javascript, if-statement, slider

I want to build a slider with buttons and I can`t figure out how should I do it.
When I hit the right button it slides 2 pages then show a blank, and thinking the problem is on the arrowRight function.
 If anyone knows why my code isn't working please explain to me.

```
//FOR SLIDER    



let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
    arrowLeft = document.querySelector("#arrow-left"),
    arrowRight = document.querySelector("#arrow-right"),
    current = 0;

function reset() {
    for (let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
        sliderImages[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function startSlide() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[0].style.display = 'block';
}
startSlide();

function slideLeft() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = 'block';
    current--
}

arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (current === 0) {
        current = sliderImages.length;
    }
    slideLeft();
})

function slideRight() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = 'block';
    current++
}
arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (current === sliderImages.length) {
        current = 0;
    }
    slideRight();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your method is perfect for that task. Usually it's two containers - one for visible part, other is full of images. It'll look something like this:

```js
const sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
    arrowLeft = document.querySelector("#arrow-left"),
    arrowRight = document.querySelector("#arrow-right"),
    container = document.querySelector(".container");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 container.style.width = 100 * sliderImages.length + "%";
 sliderImages.forEach((el) => {
  el.style.width = 100 / sliderImages.length + "%";
 })

 startSlider()
}); 

function startSlider() {

 let pos = 0;

 arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", slideLeft)
 arrowRight.addEventListener("click", slideRight)

 function slideLeft() {
  if(pos === 0) {
   pos = sliderImages.length - 1;
  } else{
   pos--;
  }

  slide()
 }

 function slideRight() {
  if(pos === sliderImages.length - 1) {
   pos = 0;
  } else {
   pos++;
  }
  slide()
 }

 function slide() {
  $(container).animate({left: -100 * pos + "%"}, 500)
 }
}
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

 body{
  width: 100%;
 }

 .outer-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
 }

 .slide > img {
  width: 100%;
 }
 
 .container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer-container">
 <div id="arrow-left">LEFT</div>
 <div id="arrow-right">RIGHT</div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://media.boingboing.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/cats.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*mONNI1lG9VuiqovpnYqicA.jpeg">
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

If you just a fix for your code, here's what I've changed:

```
arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function () {
    //Make sure that's current less than the number of images
    if (current + 1 == sliderImages.length) {
        current = 0;
    } else {
        current++;
    }
    slide();
})
//Moved checks and current position management from slide
//Functions to click listeners
arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (current === 0) {
        current = sliderImages.length - 1;
    } else {
        current--;
    }
    slide();
})
//That let me merge your two function into one
//And your checks for positions was a little off
function slide(){
    reset();
    sliderImages[current].style.display = 'block';
}
```

I hope my answer helped you. If you have any questions about this code add a comment below.